# How to scrape URL link from search box in R?

Tags: r, api, web-scraping

I would like to get URL link of the output from search box.
For example, If I type '4/271 Balmoral Road' on the search box of https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/ it shows relevant results and it leads me to go to https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/0b27093b9ce641108f7a6033b9fdae28

So in R, if I put '4/271 Balmoral Road' as a input, I want output to be 'https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/0b27093b9ce641108f7a6033b9fdae28'

Can you please help me? That would be much appreciated.

I used Rvest with following code but didn't work

```r
'https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile?query=4/271%20Balmoral%20Road' %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="ember386"]/div[1]/div/a') %>% html_attr('href')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is dynamically retrieved. You can use httr to send the address query to the server and jsonlite to handle json response from server. You get 'slugs' for the urls in the response which you need to concatenate with base string for final url.

---

**R:**

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

params = list('q' = '4/271 Balmoral Road')
d <- jsonlite::parse_json(httr::GET(url = 'https://platform.realestate.co.nz/search/v1/suggest/property', query = params))
base <- 'https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/'
print(paste0(base, d$data[[1]]$slug))
```

or version OP used:

```
library(httr) 
library(jsonlite) 

params = list('q' = '4/271 Balmoral Road') 
get <- GET(url = 'https://platform.realestate.co.nz/search/v1/suggest/property', query = params) 
json <- fromJSON(paste(get, collapse="")) 
base <- 'https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/' 
print(paste0(base, json$data[[1]]$slug))
```

---

**Py:**

```
import requests

params = (('q', '4/271 Balmoral Road'),)
r = requests.get('https://platform.realestate.co.nz/search/v1/suggest/property' , params=params).json()
links = [f"https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/{i['slug']}" for i in r['data']]
print(links[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much QHarr. I tried your R script but it didn't work. However, it works like this ```library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
params = list('q' = '4/271 Balmoral Road')
get <- GET(url = 'https://platform.realestate.co.nz/search/v1/suggest/property', query = params)
json <- fromJSON(paste(get, collapse=""))

base <- 'https://www.realestate.co.nz/profile/'
print(paste0(base, json$data[[1]]$slug))``` Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Not  sure why didn't work for you as works just fine for me but good to know there is another way :-)

Comment: Maybe different version? I uploaded other question and it will be great if you can help me again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655930/how-to-retrieve-response-by-using-post-in-r