# How to retrieve response by using POST in R

Tags: r, api, post, web-scraping, httr

If you visit https://www.aucklandcouncil.govt.nz/property-rates-valuations/pages/find-property-rates-valuation.aspx then you will see search box.

I want '905/8 Ronayne St' to be input, and '12343197398' to be output.

I am using R and tried like this but didn't work..

```
post <- POST("https://www.aucklandcouncil.govt.nz/_vti_bin/ACWeb/ACservices.svc/GetMatchingPropertyAddresses", 
             body = list('ResultCount' = "10", 'SearchText' = "905/8 Ronayne St", 'RateKeyRequired' = "false"))

content(post, "text")
```

Can you please help me? That would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The POST call returns 400 even when changing SearchText. Something in the POST call is violating the request parameters, and without seeing any documentation it is hard to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to provide the right header in R due to way sending.

**R:**

```
library(httr)

headers = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
data = '{"ResultCount":"10","SearchText":"905/8 Ronayne St","RateKeyRequired":"false"}'
r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://www.aucklandcouncil.govt.nz/_vti_bin/ACWeb/ACservices.svc/GetMatchingPropertyAddresses', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)

print(content(r)[[1]]$ACRateAccountKey)
```

---

**Py:**

```
import requests

data = {"ResultCount":"10","SearchText":"905/8 Ronayne St","RateKeyRequired":"false"}    
r = requests.post('https://www.aucklandcouncil.govt.nz/_vti_bin/ACWeb/ACservices.svc/GetMatchingPropertyAddresses', json=data).json()
print(r[0]['ACRateAccountKey'])
```

Comment: Thanks again QHarr! Much appreciated :) When I use POST function in R, Do I always need to add headers? Also, why I only need to assign 'Content-Type' for headers? (not 'Cache-Control', 'Content-Encoding' etc?)

Comment: It is about what the server has been configured to expect. Furthermore, in this case, it is particularly about how you are sending the body that the server needs to be aware of in order to handle appropriately.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I need your help again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970398/how-to-webscrap-data-if-rvest-functions-dont-work-r . It would be much appreciated if you can give answer with both R and Py :)